Highlighting only text for google sheets
Is it possible to highlight individual text in Google Sheets, just like how you can on Google Docs or Slides?

Partial text formatting is available when you are editing text in cell. Select a run of text with the mouse or arrow keys, then use format buttons in the toolbar or the usual shortcut keys to set text bold, italic, and so on. Fonts, text size and text color can also be set.
In Google Sheets, background color can only be set for whole cells. Partial text formatting does not support changing the color of text background.
